# Finding the fake algebraic identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Of the following three alleged algebraic identities, at least one is wrong.
>   $$\begin{align}
> \text{(i)}\ yz(z-y)+zx(x-z)+xy(y-x)&=(z-y)(x-z)(y-x)\\
> \text{(ii)}\ yz(z-y)+zx(x-z)+xy(y-x)&=(z-y)(z-x)(y-x)\\
> \text{(iii)}\ yz(z+y)+zx(z+x)+xy(y+x)&=(z+y)(z+x)(y+x)
> \end{align}$$
>   Which of the following statements is correct?
>
> $\text{(a)}$ Only identity $\text{(i)}$ is right
>   $\text{(b)}$ Only identity $\text{(ii)}$ is right
>   $\text{(c)}$ Identities $\text{(ii)}$ and $\text{(iii)}$ are right
>   $\text{(d)}$ All these identities are wrong

Are there any tricks that I could use for this question? Simply expanding all the equations is very time-consuming.

Comment: Why don't you just type in your question?  Are you trying to hide something?  Or do you just prefer to make it more difficult for us to answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

You look at the $xy^2$ terms so $(i)$ is obviously wrong.

Then you would look at the $xyz$ terms on both side so $(iii)$ is obviously wrong.

To verify the correctness of $(ii)$ there is no obvious way and the best you can do is expand the first two terms $yz(z-y)+zx(x-z)=z(yz-y^2+x^2-xz)=z(x^2-y^2)+z^2(y-x)$ so it is a multiple of $(x-y)$ and so is the whole left hand side. By symmetry we know the left hand side must be multiple of all three terms $(x-y),(y-z)$ and $(z-x)$ so it is either $(i)$ case or $(ii)$ case.

As we know $(i)$ is wrong $(ii)$ must be correct.